# Linux: Lost internet while using vipw. How can I unlock the file?

Tags: linux, centos, passwd, vi

I was editing the passwd file with vipw, when I briefly lost internet connectivity. When I logged back in and tried to edit again I get the error:

```
vipw: Couldn't lock file: Interrupted system call
vipw: /etc/passwd is unchanged
```

I'm assuming this means the passwd file is still locked from the interruped time I was editing it. How can I fix this?

Comment: ls -l /etc/.pwd.lock or strace -e open vipw, after that you can delete the lock file

Comment: Thanks. I removed the .pwd.lock and passwd.lock files and that did it. Put you comment as an answer, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: this is one of the reasons I use tmux

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check if the /etc/.pwd.lock exists and if it's there rm /etc/.pwd.lock
In this way you can solve your issue